# How to call parent destruct in PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

I want destroy the PDO connection, I can do this creating a private variable with this structure: `$this->_pdo = new PDO(credentials here)` and then in the same class:

```
function __destruct()
{
    $this->_pdo = NULL;
}
```

But for some operation like `lastInsertedId` I need to call the parent construct. So I need to use this structure:

```
public function __construct($dbhost, $dbname, $dbuser = 'root', $dbpass = '', $dbtype = 'mysql') {
    parent::__construct($dbtype . ':host=' . $dbhost . ';dbname=' . $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);
}
```

How can I destroy the connection using the parent construct?

Comment: Is this class extending the PDO object?

Comment: Just as an aside, constantly connecting and disconnecting via PDO is probably wasteful. If I were you I'd instantiate it outside the class and inject it when you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a good way to do this unfortunately. You've got two scenarios here

1. You're instantiating PDO and saving it as a class member. At this point you have a variable pointing to the instance so removing that reference will cause it to be eligible for garbage collection
2. You're instantiating PDO from a child class. Here you can't destroy the instance because the child **IS** the instance. You'd have to go back to the variable holding the instance and `unset()` it or something similar

Without the class itself I'm not sure we can be more help than this.

Comment: well I guess in my wrapper a `die()` could solve the situation